# Problem when using the specifier `b` of `xparse` with tabulars

Tags: expl3, arrays, xparse

Edit: Phelype Oleinik has opened an issue in the bug tracker of LaTeX3 for that issue:  https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/839

---

The following code provides an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyEnv}{b}
  {$\begin{array}{cc}#1\end{array}$}
  {}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyEnv}x&y\end{MyEnv} 

\begin{tabular}{cc}
smth & \begin{MyEnv}x&y\end{MyEnv}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Is it a bug of the specifier `b` of `xparse`?

Comment: In the tabular, just enclose your environment in braces.

Comment: I know that it works when enclosing with braces but that's not my question.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/839

Comment: Fixed with [this commit](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/c472d9c).  Should be available with the next `xparse` release.  The fix is more or less as David proposed, except that `\group_align_safe_begin/end:` does not create an extra group around the environment: `\edef\x{\group_align_safe_begin: \group_align_safe_end:}\show\x` expands to nothing, whereas `\edef\x{{\ifnum0=`}\fi \ifnum0=`{\fi}}\show\x` expands to `{}`.  Normally you should see no difference.

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik: Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Phelype commented we looked at this and might add the special table group required to hide nested `&` but meanwhile you can add them using the new environment hook feature.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{MyEnv}{b}
  {$\begin{array}{cc}#1\end{array}$}
  {}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{MyEnv}{{\ifnum0=`}\fi}
\AfterEndEnvironment{MyEnv}{\ifnum0=`{\fi}}

\begin{document}

\begin{MyEnv}x&y\end{MyEnv} 

\begin{tabular}{cc}
smth & \begin{MyEnv}x&y\end{MyEnv}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```